# PHP timing out inside a public function

Tags: php, html, function

Im pulling a "large" sql query from the batabase, 50000 records. Its completed in about 5 seconds but after the pull, I run it through a function to create a html table, it keeps timing out for some reason. I can limit the query to <30k and it will execute the php script in about 19 seconds, but anything larger and the table doesnt show up, yet everything prior on the page loads.

I tried reseting the time limit but it did not resolve the issue

```
 ignore_user_abort(true);
 set_time_limit(0);
```

What could be causing the time out when generating the table?

edit1:

I modified the php.ini file to allow longer execution times, that did not resolve the issue.

```
public function report_table($data, $header_spacing, $column)
{


    $html = "<div class='accordion_div'>";

    foreach($data as $d_row){

        $title = $d_row[0][$column];
        $html .= $this->accorion_button($title);
        $html .= "<div class='panel'><table border='0' style='$align; width: 980px;'>";
        foreach($d_row as $d1){


            $html .= "<tr>";
            $x=0;
            $y=$x+1;
            $html .=    "<td style='width: $header_spacing[$x];' scope='col' >&nbsp;</td>";
            foreach($d1 as $d){

                    $html .=    "<td style='width: $header_spacing[$y];' scope='col' >$d</td>";

                $x++;
                $y++;
            }

            $html .= "</tr>";
        }

            $html .= "</table>";
        $html .= "</div>";

    }



    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Are you using pagination? Why not show few hundred at a time by using it?

Comment: Why don't you limit your SQL query to less records, make table let's say.. 500 rows and making pagination? I don't think it's good practice to have lots of rows in table in html. Browser may take too much memory.

Comment: BTW.. your timeout... Check your php.ini there is I believe 60 second limit, so increase it

Comment: Please share the code where you generate the html table. Maybe an extra set of eyes could catch some optimization you missed. But as others say, pagination would be a more robust solution

Comment: @MartinJoneš I suppose that his main problem is with the browser when it tries to render all this huge amount of data. So, I would try a pagination system: https://www.phpflow.com/php/simple-pagination-with-php-and-mysql-using-jquery/

Comment: @Ikillnukes - making pagination in PHP would be better then jQuery. If variable of $_GET['page'] is not set, then its page 1 so he would make his SQL query like "LIMIT $page $limit" so it will let's say select rows 1-50" and the processing wouldn't take 15 seconds or so. And passing it thru functions will be also faster.

Comment: I had a similar requirement displaying more than 65K records, used the following jquery for pagination and it works perfectly. Check this: https://codepen.io/PhilipJohnBasile/pen/weorgm

Comment: Another thing you should do in php is Increase PHP Memory Allowance Using ini_set(),  ini_set('memory_limit','512M');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you should do to avoid such things:

1. Increase PHP Memory Allowance Using ini_set(), `ini_set('memory_limit','512M');`

so your code would be:

```
public function report_table($data, $header_spacing, $column)
{
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
//then your loop
}
```

2. Add pagination either php or jquery, I had a similar requirement displaying more than 65K records, used the following jquery for pagination and it works perfectly. Check this: [codepen.io/PhilipJohnBasile/pen/weorgm](http://codepen.io/PhilipJohnBasile/pen/weorgm)

Comment: This fixed it. Great job